# is there a more efficient way to normalize a set of data in sklearn or other python lib

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to normalize a set of data with L2 norm.

[image]

I've defined a function to demo this (would be extended to multiple features).

```
>>> def fnormlz(data1, data2):
...     data1 = stats.zscore(data1)
...     data2 = stats.zscore(data2)
...     data = np.concatenate((data1.reshape(-1,1) ,data2.reshape(-1,1)), axis=1)
...     dn = np.linalg.norm(data,axis=1, keepdims=True)
...     x1 = np.squeeze(data1) / np.squeeze(dn)
...     x2 = np.squeeze(data2) / np.squeeze(dn)
...     return x1, x2
```

this function seems that work well.

```
>>> data1 = np.random.normal(scale=10.0, size = 30)
>>> stats.describe(data1)
DescribeResult(nobs=30, minmax=(-14.480351639879657, 21.694340665659155), mean=1.7693402703870142, variance=70.96823479863615, skewness=0.48446965640611006, kurtosis=0.029201481246492023)
>>> data2 = np.random.normal(scale=100.0, size = 30)
>>> stats.describe(data2)
DescribeResult(nobs=30, minmax=(-131.3594947316083, 198.39728417503383), mean=-7.255658382442095, variance=5255.736619957794, skewness=0.6343298691171217, kurtosis=0.4738823408913704)
>>> data1, data2 = fnormlz(data1, data2)
>>> print(stats.describe(data1))
DescribeResult(nobs=30, minmax=(-0.9973779251196154, 0.9881011078096066), mean=-0.05634450329772703, variance=0.46458361781960184, skewness=0.06081037409100871, kurtosis=-1.4984969471774237)
>>> print(stats.describe(data2))
DescribeResult(nobs=30, minmax=(-0.9896047983762021, 0.9884599298308269), mean=-0.03121868793266298, variance=0.565606751634083, skewness=0.04677252893105364, kurtosis=-1.655597055471202)
```

the result is as expected. is there a more efficient way to do this?

the variance scaling in [sklearn doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html) could be used for this? if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `fnormlz_v2` may be what you need. but the zscore processing comes from your original code may hide some info in data.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from scipy import stats

def fnormlz_v2(X):
    X = stats.zscore(X)
    X_norm, norm = normalize(X, norm='l2', axis=1, copy=True, return_norm=True)
    return X_norm

feature1 = np.random.normal(scale=10.0, size = 100)
feature2 = np.random.normal(scale=100.0, size = 100)
data = np.concatenate((feature1.reshape(-1,1) ,feature2.reshape(-1,1)), axis=1)

data_norm = fnormlz_v2(data)

for i in [data, data_norm]:
    print(stats.describe(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`sklearn.preprocessing.normalize`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from scipy import stats

a = np.random.normal(scale=10.0, size = 30)
b = data2 = np.random.normal(scale=100.0, size = 30)

c = np.concatenate((a.reshape(-1,1) ,b.reshape(-1,1)), axis=1)

d, norm = normalize(c, norm='l2', axis=1, copy=True, return_norm=True)

a_n = a / norm
b_n = b / norm

for x in [a, a_n, b, b_n]:
    print(stats.describe(x))
```